# Wordpress Multisite Domain Mapping Only Redirects

Tags: php, wordpress

I am successfully able to map 2 DNS entries to my wordpress site. I have made a network and then installed the mu domain mapping plugin. The multisite is in the form of a directory/sub-folder. So when I open the non-primary url, it maps correctly to the sub-folder site and the corresponding page gets displayed.

```
DNS -> WP Site
original-name -> original-name
second-name -> original-name/sub-folder
```

Now the problem is the Browser shows the

```
original-name/sub-folder
```

in the URL section instead of the second-name (DN through which i accessed the site).

In other words, this is a mere redirection to the mapped sub-folder. Is there any way to have all my links on my page and the Browser URL display the other domain name and not the folder structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. Under the site (second-name), go to Tools -> Domain Mapping -> Add new domain, add the domain here and make it primary. Making it primary is the key. That is what wp "redirects" to.